# Линейные списки на Си

Tags: c, список

Затянул с лабараторками по Си в универе до сессии и теперь в горячке пытаюсь сделать. Пока первый курс и ничего сложного нет, но основательно застрял на Линейных Списках.

Все статьи, что нахожу вмещают в себя код на С++, который я не знаю. И хоть в будущем я его выучить хочу, но сейчас на него времени нет. Так вот господа, может подсобите литературой, которая показывает принцип списков на пальцах и основательно разжевывает часть с кодом, который написан именно на Си?

Мне бы хотя бы 1 программку, в которой организованы основные функции и расписаны принципы работы через комментарии -- дальше можно будет и с той лит-рой что я нашел работать.

---

Если кто-то возьмется помочь самостоятельно -- был бы благодарен за показ на основе задания "Есть односвязный линейный список слов. Написать программу, которая выводит на экран первые буквы каждого слова списка по очереди."

Comment: Что-то вроде (полноценный ответ лень писать).

    struct item {
      struct item *next;
      char *word;
    };

    void prilist(struct item *list) {
      while (list) {
        putchar(list->word[0]);
        list = list->next;
      }
      puts("");
    }

    void pushlist(struct item **list, struct item *e) // добавляет как в стек
    {
       e->next = *list;
       *list = e;
    }

    int main() {
      struct item *list = 0, *e;
      while (e = get_data())
        pushlist(&list, e);
      prilist(list);
      return 0;
    }

Для `get_data()` места мало. Сами напишите.

Comment: Еще полезная функция


    struct item *
    reverse (struct item *list)
    {
      struct item *rlist = 0, *t;
    
      while (list) {
        t = list;
        list = list->next;
        t->next = rlist;
        rlist = t;
      }
      
      return rlist;
    }

Теперь можно печатать в порядке ввода слов

    int main() {
       ...
       list = reverse(list);
       prilist(list);
    }


@robben1234, обратите внимание на возврат указателя из reverse().

Списки это простая штука (когда Вы хорошо понимаете, как устроена память, как структуры размещаются в ней и что такое указатель).

Comment: @avp: Кстати, о понимании того, что есть указатель: http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/12/what-are-the-fundamental-rules-of-pointers/ (Эрик вообще-то гуру и один из разработчиков C#, но всё же). Может быть, статья пригодится для объяснения другим.

Comment: И еще немного техники


    struct item *
    insert (struct item *e1, struct item *e2) // вставим e2 после e1
    {
      e2->next = e1->next;
      e1->next = e2;
      return e2;
    }

    
    main () {
       .... 
      struct item *t;
      for (t = list; t && t->next; t = t->next);
      printf ("last word in list: %s\n", t ? t->word : "<empty list>");
      if (t) { // и введите еще несколько слов...
        while (e = get_data()) 
          t = insert(t, e);
        prilist(list);
      }
    }

Comment: @VladD, ага. Прочел. Просто здорово, что Вы привели здесь такую ссылку.

--

Очень хорошее объяснение, только на мой вкус немного длинновато 

(хотя, конечно, без листочка бумаги в клетку, карандаша и ластика быстрее рассказать не получится :)).

--

Comment: @avp: Это, кстати, да, один рисунок стоит тысячи слов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@robben1234](/users/19663/robben1234)](/users/19663/robben1234), комментарии кончились, а захотелось немного дополнить.

Если функцию `insert()` немного изменить:

```
struct item *
insert (struct item *e1, struct item *e2) // вставим e2 после e1
{
  if (e1) {
    e2->next = e1->next;
    e1->next = e2;
  } else
    e2->next = 0;

  return e2;
}
```

то ее удобно использовать для построения списка в порядке появления элементов

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

....

int 
main (int ac, char *av[]) 
{
  struct item *list = 0, *t = 0, *e;

  while (e = get_data()) {
    t = insert(t, e);
    if (!list)
      list = t;
  }
  prilist(list);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

А вообще, хочу сказать, что односвязные списки (в отличие от двусвязных) это не та область, в которой стоит писать что-то вроде библиотечных функций. Работа с ними обычно просто естественно встраивается в основной код алгоритма.

Например, вместо

```
  while (e = get_data())
    pushlist(&list, e);
```

вполне можно написать

```
  while (e = get_data())
    e->next = list, list = e;
```

Если заинтересовались и будут какие-то вопросы по программированию списков -- не стесняйтесь, задавайте.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй замутить линейный список сначала без динамической памяти - а чисто на личном обычном массиве (глобальном) структур.

где 2 поля . как обычно поле значение , а вот вместо поля указателя(типизированного) на некоторый адрес памяти по которому расположенна такая же структура пусть В ТВОЁМ варианте будет индекс твоего массива.

реализуй все нужные процедуры , добавление , удаление, поиск

*(этот пункт не обязателен)и как бонус можешь написать свой менеджер памяти который будет или вести постояный список свободных ячеек , либо по типу сборщика мусора

и тебе станет всё ясно.

переписывание на вариант с обычными указателями и использования стандартного malloc/free  даст тебе обычную реализацию

вообще полезней разделять понимание абстракции и реализации.

так как статические массивы легче инспектировать  в IDE  то попробуй переписать свой/чужой код для варианта

```
struct{
    char[10] value;
    int next;
}[9999] YouMEM;
```

и поиграться с ним.

Comment: Абстрагироваться от _указателей_ в языке _C_? Хм, не знаю, может быть это и круто.

Comment: Интересное упражнение. 

Может оказаться полезным, если ТС потребуется когда-нибудь потом работать, например, с shared memory.

(или делать списки в FORTRAN IV)

Comment: дык индексы и есть "указатели" в сущьностном .

синтаксис другой ага , но и то и то некоторое число(ключ - строка бит) которое в случае индекса базировано с конкретного адреса(начало массива)  и в случае указателя - вся память(процесса) такой массив :)

а вот пониманию способствует. т.е указатель это не нечто "вау" , а ровно наличие возможности индексировать память

Comment: @qulinxao, в принципе, Вы правы. 

Однако, судя по реакции (т.е. ее отсутствию) автора, скорее всего он вряд ли заинтересуется такими этюдами.

Comment: @qulinxao: Я понимаю. Указатель есть не что иное, как индекс в массиве, представляющем собой всю память.

Абстракция сама по себе хороша (я бы абстрактный указатель назвал хэндлом только). Но язык C настолько плотно завязан на указатели, что я позволил себе усомниться в ней.

В любом случае, этюд изящный, да. Но не для новичков (да не обидится ТС).